# What do you ask when you want to join a queue?

Tags: phrases, word-usage

If you are wanting to join a long queue what do you ask the person at the back?

1. "Is this the **start** of the queue?"
2. "Is this the **end** of the queue?"

Consider people at the supermarket counter. Is the start of the queue the place you go to start queuing?

Comment: Please **include the [research](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/how-much-research-is-needed)** you've done.

Comment: Are you referring to people queuing up in a physical line such as at a supermarket checkout register, or do you mean the extended sense of a [first-in first-out abstract data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)) in computer science?

Comment: The people at the supermarket

Comment: The last person is at the end of the queue. I don't see this as at all ambiguous.

Comment: The queue starts here and ends over there.  Can you see the person in the red jumper ? They're the last person/the end of the queue.  Surely?

Comment: @Dan is the start of the queue the place you go to start queuing?

Comment: Reopen the question! The *end of the queue* is where *you* start queuing (thanks @MartinSmith).

Comment: Not too sure why this question is marked off topic? @MartinSmith 's comment is the exact reason the usage is not clear.

Comment: Voted to reopen. Physically, the start of the queue is the person who will be serviced next, and the end is serviced last. Temporally, the start of the queue is the place you enter the queue and the end is where you exit the queue.

Answer (score 1):

From my part of the world (eastern England) people commonly speak of the head and the tail of the queue. I find that pretty unambiguous. People join the tail of the queue and are served from the head.

Comment: Where exactly in eastern England? I was Norfolk born and bred. And I never heard anyone refer to the 'tail' of the queue. Head/front and end/back was all I ever knew.

Comment: I'm near Cambridge but I didn't think it was all that regional. It looks as if we've both heard of the head of a queue and I've certainly heard of the back of a queue as well as the tail.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the last person to arrive is at the ***foot*** of the line (or queue).

You will find plenty of references on [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22foot%20of%20the%20line%22) - here's [one](https://books.google.com/books?id=jBtDSf1VzQkC&pg=PT168&dq=Stranger%20in%20a%20Strange%20Land%20%22foot%20of%20the%20line%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Stranger%20in%20a%20Strange%20Land%20%22foot%20of%20the%20line%22&f=false) I remembered from Robert Heinlein's *Stranger in a Strange Land*.

Answer (score -1):

Queues have two ends so "end of the queue" is certainly ambiguous.

A lot of commentators are claiming that this is not at all ambiguous and "end of the queue" always means back. A quick Google search for the phrase "reached the end of the queue" shows people definitely using it to mean the opposite end in that instance. [Example 1](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=wRioAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA72&dq=%22Reached%20the%20end%20of%20the%20queue%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Reached%20the%20end%20of%20the%20queue%22&f=false), [Example 2](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=6TuuAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT8&dq=%22Reached%20the%20end%20of%20the%20queue%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Reached%20the%20end%20of%20the%20queue%22&f=false)

Similarly "start of the queue" could be interpreted to mean either the part of the queue containing the people that started the queue (front) or the part of the queue where new entrants must join to start queueing (back).

When you say last position in a queue I assume you are talking about the person that joined last.

In that case I would say "the back of the queue" to avoid any doubt.

Comment: Lines have two ends but 'the end of the line' often has a default meaning.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth in what context are you using the word "line"? If you say "the end of the line" referring to the Central line for example that could certainly mean either end.

Comment: I'll be less hedgy, then. 'The end of the queue' would be taken to mean 'the back of the queue' in almost all cases. Pragmatics trumps strict logic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I agree, except that I would say "all cases" instead of "almost all cases".

Comment: @TonyK In at least one location in central Manchester, bus queues often start from the centre of the shelter and develop both ways (one is never sure which end of the shelter one's bus is going to be able to stop at). People add on to both ends: the default usage doesn't work here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: On the contrary, in such a case "the end of the queue" has two referents, and "the back of the queue" has the same two referents.

Comment: @TonyK Are you saying that the default usage of 'the end of the queue' _isn't_ 'the other end from the front as defined by the person arriving first'? I'd say that that's contrarian.

Comment: Bus lines such as those @TonyK describes are not queues in the usual sense, precisely because there is no defined point of processing and releasing from the line. I would argue that in this case there is no queue until the bus arrives. The release-point is then defined, and the segments either side of the door become two separate queues with the same processing point. At this time, the point of processing becomes the start/beginning/head and the points furthest from the bus become the ends/tails of the queues. I very rarely hear bus lines being called queues -- probably for this reason.